# Server to server authentication with Node.js, Passport

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-cookies, passport.js

I have two services running on different sub-domains: 1) Node.js, Express, PassportJS,  2) PHP based. Both services are exposed in same portal, in order to avoid requiring user to enter credentials twice, we call Node.js login API from PHP server. Node returns session cookie (`connect.sid`), we forward this to client with domain set to `<<rootdomain>>.com`. Now when client calls Node.js, we can see cookie being sent to Node but still Node fails to authenticate.

I have verified following things:

1. Login API call from PHP server to Node returns success with `connect.sid` cookie and adds session entry into Redis server (We are using Redis for storing sessions)
2. Cookie is set correctly in browser
3. When browser calls Node.js `connect.sid` cookie is sent to server
4. If we call login API directly from client, everything works as expected. Basically stand alone Node app works without any issues.

I am curious whether Node uses User-agent, IP or something to validate `connect.sid` cookie? Or is it something related to Passport/Express session params values? What might be wrong? FYI, currently site is *not* running on SSL.

Here are my session params:

```
store = new RedisStore({
      port: 6379,
      host: 'localhost',
      client : redis
  });
var sess = {
  store: store,
  secret: 'some secret',
  rolling: true,
  cookie: { maxAge : 36000000, secure: false },
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
sortName: 0,
sortModified:0,
sortSize: 0
};
```

Thanks in advance